# query to find value absent for month

Tags: sql-server

I have a table like below:

```
CREATE TABLE TestT (Id INT, Dates DATE)

INSERT TestT VALUES
(1,'2018-01-01'),
(2,'2018-01-01'),
(3,'2018-01-01'),
(4,'2018-01-01'),
(1,'2018-02-01'),
(3,'2018-02-01'),
(4,'2018-02-01'),
(1,'2018-03-01'),
(2,'2018-03-01'),
(4,'2018-03-01')
```

---

I need output like :

```
Id      Date      Status
1       1/1/2018    Y
2       1/1/2018    Y
3       1/1/2018    Y
4       1/1/2018    Y
1       2/1/2018    Y
2       NULL        N
3       2/1/2018    Y
4       2/1/2018    Y
1       3/1/2018    Y
2       3/1/2018    Y
3       NULL        N
4       3/1/2018    Y
```

Comment: Are the groups only ever 4 records, or should we assume arbitrary min and max values for each date group?

Comment: Groups can be more than 4. I just changed SELECT Id AS Val FROM TestT for b to run my query for all records. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My approach would be to generate all of the possible records, and then re-join the original table to detect the missing ones.

```
SELECT DISTINCT
  a.Dates,
  b.VAL,
  CASE 
    WHEN c.Id IS NOT NULL THEN 'Y'
    ELSE 'N'
  END AS Status
FROM
  TestT a
LEFT JOIN
  (SELECT 1 AS VAL UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4) b
  ON 1 = 1
LEFT JOIN
  TestT c
  ON c.Dates = a.Dates
  AND c.Id = b.VAL
```

Answer (score 0):

The idea here is is to get distinct of both fields cross join it and left join back to existing table.

```
Select a.id, b.dates, case when c.id is null then 'n' else 'y' end status from
(Select distinct Id from testt) a
Cross join (select distinct dates from testt) b
Left outer join testt c on a.id=c.id and b.status=c.status
```